# Typescript function generic can infer type automatically, is there an equivalent for object generic type?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, existential-type

```
function <Obj extends object>funName(o:Obj): Obj{
  ...
}
```

Function generic as above enforces a certain relationship between params and return types, without forcing the user to actually pass a type.

Is there an equivelant object generic type (POJO - plain old JS object), without forcing the user to pass a type?

```
type Props = <S extends string>{
  selectedTab: S 
  tabs: Record<S, any>
}

const props1: Props = { //ok 
  selectedTab: "about"
  tabs: {
    about: {...} 
  }
}

const props2: Props = { //Error
  selectedTab: "contact us"
  tabs: {
    about: {...} 
  }
}
```

I know this could be achieved by passing a type.

```
const props1: Props<"about"> = { 
  ...
}
```

But since automatic inference is possible for functions, perhaps it can also be used for objects.

Answer (score 0):

There is no automatic inference for type generics. The only way to omit a generic when using a type is if it provides a default like this:

```
Props<S = string> {
   selectedTab: S;
   tabs: Record<S, any>;
}
```

However, this does not achive inference like you suggest in your question. This only sets the generic to a default if no other value is provided. With the above type definition, the following would still be valid, because `S` is defaulted to `string`:

```
let p: Props = {
   selectedTab: 'contact us'
   tabs: {
      about: {}
   }
}
```

The reason is that in a function call you automatically specify the generic's type by the parameters' types. In your example, the function call will return whatever type you are passing to it.

Also, even if there was a feature like this, the example you marked with `//Error`  would still be valid as `S` could be inferred as `string` or `'contact us' | 'about'` which would match the generic's constraint `S extends string`.